High number of Outliers
I was working on a dataset about some credit card fraud detection. The box plot for the "Transaction Amount col." showing a lot of outliers. Can anyone suggest what to do? Should i cap the outliers, remove them or any ML model that's robust to outliers.

Are there fraudulent transactions in these outliers? If so then removing them would be bad as your model would be missing these points to train on.
If the outliers are important and deviate a lot, you could use scaling to have the outliers not impact the model as much and still retain all data.
You could also separate the outliers, treat them as a second dataset and build a second model. Then use both models together in an ensemble
